# Cakephp email component sending 2 emails instead of 1

Tags: cakephp

I am using the Email Component of Cake 1.3 to send emails to users in the system.

There's a loop going through all users, putting some content into the email and sending it.

Random users are receiving an email twice even though programmaticaly it shouldnt be possible.

Being very general the function looks like this:

```
foreach($users as $user){
    //magic
    $this->Email->send();
    $this->Email->reset();
}
```

So there's no reason for the email to be sent more than once to each user but still some are receiving two emails.. One day a user is getting 1 email and the other day he is getting 2 emails (this function is executed once daily).

I have no idea why is this happening... every comment will be usefull, thanks.

Comment: Have you checked your users table by running a select count and grouping it by email address? Some email addresses may be in there twice.

Comment: first thought: nice magic in code, second one: are there user duplicatesin your users aray?

Comment: There are no duplicates. This function is executed once daily. The problem is sometimes the users are getting just 1 email and the other day the same users are getting 2.

Comment: Try being very specific, instead of very general

Comment: How is the $users array generated? Maybe you merged some arrays and got duplicates?

Comment: Im sure that there are no duplicates in the users array.